# Lisp: Function that returns the predecessor of an element in a list

Tags: lisp

```
(pred 'r '(p q r)) -> q
```

Here's my idea-
- I have tried finding the function that returns the length of a specific element, but due to my lack of syntactical knowledge, I am unable to use the function. 
- By using the length function as my helper function, I am trying to find the predecessor of an element in the list.

I hope that gives you guys some idea to start with or if you guys have a better idea, please let me know and also please show the coding too..

Thank you!

Comment: be sure to read about accepting an answer that was most helpful to you and why you should do that. search the "help" in SO's taskbar above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current attempt, here's a corrected version (with corrected indentation, as a bonus :-)):

```
(defun pred (x l)
  (cond ((null (cdr l)) (car l))
        ((eq (cadr l) x) (car l))
        (t (pred x (cdr l)))))
```

Are you sure you want to return the last element of the list if your expected element isn't found? It seems...strange, I'd have thought nil is a better return value.

---

Update: the OP wanted to implement both successor and predecessor functions. Here's how I'd implement them, in Scheme. (Sorry, not doing your homework for you, but if you know how to translate Scheme into Common Lisp, your life would be easier.)

```
(define (succ x lst)
  (cond ((memv x lst) => (lambda (mem)
                           (and (pair? (cdr mem))
                                (cadr mem))))
        (else #f)))

(define (pred x lst)
  (let loop ((prev #f)
             (rest lst))
    (cond ((null? rest) #f)
          ((eqv? (car rest) x) prev)
          (else (loop (car rest) (cdr rest))))))
```

and while `memv` is built-in to Scheme, you could implement it yourself quite simply:

```
(define (memv x lst)
  (let loop ((rest lst))
    (cond ((null? rest) #f)
          ((eqv? (car rest) x) rest)
          (else (loop (cdr rest))))))
```

In particular, note the similarity between `memv` and `pred`.

Comment: So, as for the successor, I need to change the (car l) of the third line, I tried car ( cdr ( cdr l))) ... but i am not getting the desired results ..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused .. :(

Comment: @lurker That's what I said in the bottom paragraph. :-)

Comment: Oh yep, you got it. :) I couldn't find the "current attempt" so I lost context.

Comment: @lurker It's in the comment to Jerry Coffin's answer. :-)

Comment: Ah ok. Missed that. I hate reading code in comments. For a short time, I was on a mission trying to get OPs to post their attempts in their actual problem statement and not the comments, but I had given up.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I am still confused on this ... From what I understand from line 3, you are searching for your expected element and if not found, you keep looking for your desired element through the recursion call on line 4 ... and as for the predecessor, if you find your expected element you return (car l) ... and, I think returning (car (cdr l)), would help me find the successor in the similar manner .. but, I am not getting the right answer .. am I doing something wrong ..?? and also I did not understand why I should be returning nil to find the successor ... sorry!! I am just dumb .. :/

Comment: @user123378 Are you trying to find the _predecessor_ or the _successor_? Your question is about the predecessor. Finding the successor involves a totally different, but much easier, approach.

Comment: I am trying to find the successor

Comment: @user123378 the example you posted is predecessor.

Comment: yeah, i am aware of that, I am also trying to see how to find the successor ... i'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: @user123378 `(define succ (x l) (cadr (member x l)))`

Comment: what's member function ?

Comment: @user123378 I hate to say RTFM, but seriously: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm :-P

Comment: i'm sorry Chris ... well is there a way without using the member function and only use the car, cdr and cons ////

Comment: @user123378 Sorry, I'm not going to do your homework for you. Professional Lispers use all the tools that their language gives them. You already have a huge leg up with the code I've already posted; make the most of it!

Comment: Hey Chris, I got an idea to reverse the list and then use the same function as we did for predecessor to find the successor.. here's my attempt, but i am sorry again, i am not getting the right answer, sorry !! and rev, is the reverse of the list 
(defun succ (x l) -
  (cond ((null (cdr l)) (car l))        
        - ((eq (cadr (rev l)) x) (car l)) 
        - (t (succ x (cdr l)))))

Comment: @user123378 Ewwwww! Do not use a list-reversal approach, that's the worst of all possible solutions. Why don't you implement your own `member` (it is trivial, I promise) and use that?

Comment: I totally agree, but I am only restricted to certain primitives, predicates and control flows.

Comment: @user123378 Yes, you can implement `member` yourself using only those primitives. It's really that simple.

Comment: @user123378 I've implemented all the functions (predecessor, successor, and member) in Scheme, for you to learn concepts from, if you want to know how it's done "from first principles". You will have to translate them to Common Lisp to be able to use them in your homework, of course; I won't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't particularly need a `length` function to do this.

The obvious classical approach would be that if the `cadr` of the list equals the element you want, return the `car` of the list. Otherwise, return the search function on the `cdr` of the list. Other than that, you just need to deal with the boundary conditions (e.g., list that's empty or contains only one item).

Comment: Here's my attempt (although there's a lot of errors), and also assuming that the list has atleast one element. (also - means next line) 

(defun     
- pred (x l)
- (cond
- ((nil (cdr l)) (car l)) 
- ((eq(cdr l) x) (car l))
- (t (pred(cdl l)))
- )
- )